# Watson Assistant on IBM ICP - Serviceid-Secret Error while Installing

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-watson, ibm-cloud-private

I'm trying to install Watson Assistant for ICP V1.0.0.1 to my IBM ICP 2.1.0.3. I've followed the tutorial on https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant-icp/install.html#install word by word. However, at the last step, when I want to start the deployment, I'm getting an error saying:

```
Internal service error : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = release watsonist failed: Secret "-serviceid-secret" is invalid: metadata.name: Invalid value: "-serviceid-secret": a DNS-1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')
```

My release name is watsonist and left every value at default in my first trial, changed passwords in my second and I'm getting the same error even with different release names.

What do you think might be the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to your deployment YAML file definition?

Comment: Unfortunately, no I don't.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the recommended solution to install Watson Assistant on ICP is to use Helm CLI rather than the UI with following commands (for V1.0.0):

Download the package you have pushed:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://mycluster.icp:8443/helm-repo/requiredAssets/ibm-watson-assistant-prod-1.0.0.tgz
```

Then:

```
tar -xzvf ibm-watson-assistant-prod-1.0.0.tgz ibm-watson-assistant-prod/values.yaml -C ./ --strip-components=1
```

-- You will have access to values.yaml file for personalization modifications with the command above.

Then:

```
sed -i -- ‘{s/{icp-url}/mycluster.icp/g}’ values.yaml
```

And, finally:

```
helm install --tls --namespace conversation --name assistant -f values.yaml ibm-watson-assistant-prod-1.0.0.tgz
```

**Make sure** your Helm and Tiller version is **2.7.3+icp**. This version is not an official release that you can find on Helm's Github page. You need to extract and install it from ICP image loaded on Docker with the following command:

```
docker run -e LICENSE=accept --net=host -v /usr/local/bin:/data ibmcom/icp-helm-api:1.0.0 cp /usr/src/app/public/cli/linux-amd64/helm /data
```

Moreover, if you're getting an error saying there's a problem with your tiller and show `ImagePullBackoff` or `ErrImagePull` on your tiller pod's status, then you need to open your tiller deploy's configuration file on `vi` using the command below:

`kubectl -n kube-system edit deployment tiller-deploy`

And replace

`gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.7.3`

with

`ibmcom/tiller:v2.7.3-icp`.

Also, it is recommended that you update each node's `/etc/hosts` file or your DNS server with following:

```
<< Master VIP Address >> CA Domain (default: mycluster.icp)
<< Proxy VIP Address >> Watson Assistant Subdomain (default: assistant.mycluster.icp)
```